# Python - How to view Columns Names of a csv file

Tags: pandas, csv

In my CSV there is 162 columns. When I use the FileName.Columns to list the name of columns, It showing only few. How I can see the whole column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the data into a data frame you can use thee columns property to access the column names.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
for column_name in df.columns:
    print(column_name)
```

Comment: list(data.columns.values)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just do a shallow read of one line of the file and then peek at the column names:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your_file.csv', nrow=1)
col_names = df.head()
col_names
```